# `go test` for package fails but individually test run fine, and package compiles fine

Tags: unit-testing, go

When I execute `go test` for a whole package the tests fail with:

```
$ go test github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/...
# github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/backends
go1: internal compiler error: in read_type, at go/gofrontend/import.cc:669
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gccgo-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
FAIL    github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/backends [build failed]
?       github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/cmd        [no test files]
# github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/httpd
go1: internal compiler error: in read_type, at go/gofrontend/import.cc:669
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gccgo-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
FAIL    github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/httpd [build failed]
?       github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/logging    [no test files]
```

While the above tests fail `go install` builds correctly and I can run each of my individual tests correctly:

```
$ go test github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/backends/backends_test.go
ok      command-line-arguments  0.025s


go test github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/httpd/handlers_test.go
ok      command-line-arguments  0.021s
```

Has anyone ran into this before?  I am brand new to Go, and to get around this I have just been executing each one of my test files individually.

The output of go build is nothing

```
$ go build github.com/dm03514/go-edu-db/...
$
```

go version is

```
$ go version
go version xgcc (Ubuntu 4.9-20140406-0ubuntu1) 4.9.0 20140405 (experimental) [trunk revision 209157] linux/amd64
```

Comment: What is the output of running ``go build``?

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: @JimB version is 4.9.0

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. I ended up just commenting out different tests until I was able to see useful output and to see when it would start passing. The root cause was one of my concurrently running test goroutines was calling `t.Errorf` (specifically, I was using the [testify/assert package](https://github.com/stretchr/testify), but this eventually calls t.Errorf) after the test was completed. The output using `go test -v` eventually had this error message:

> Fail in goroutine after TestTradeReader_Subscribe has completed

For me, this happened because I was using an `httptest.Server` (which runs concurrently during my test) and was checking input on a test case that exited quickly and didn't require this check.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that helped me.. If you use plenty of tests in a loop and you create some of the mocked services OUTSIDE the loop, it may cause some problem.

TO SOLVE THIS: just move your mocked objects creation for your complex tests inside the loop and it will be done!

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a routine leak. You maybe be modifying/updating a global variable  in the test and not reverting for the second test.
Second reason for this error could be your test in not running in a closed env. and effecting other test after.
you can re-structure your test so that the test giving error runs at first so that it succeeds

Comment: can you share the order of tests which worked for you? that would be a better answer which offer something to the reader

Comment: I am not sure, I just tried randomly moving the order of the tests and running `go test` after every change and it suddenly started working.